# Assign a constant value to an ARM register

Tags: ghidra, decompiler, game-hacking, dnspy

I was reversing an `libil2cpp.so` and decompiled it using `ghidra` and as of now my assembly language knowledge is very limited and studied it long time btw I had an assembly code like this:

```
                    ********************************************
                    *                 FUNCTION                 *
                    ********************************************
                    void __stdcall gameOverANDTERMINATED(int param_1, float param_2)
         void               <VOID>           <RETURN>
         int                r0:4             param_1
         float              r1:4             param_2
                                                                                                      
    0037127c 70 4c 2d e9              stmdb           sp!,{r4 r5 r6 r10 r11 lr}
    00371280 10 b0 8d e2              add             r11, sp, #0x10
    00371284 04 8b 2d ed              vpush           {d8,d9}
    00371288 0c 61 9f e5              ldr             r6, [DAT_0037139c]                                                                                      ; = 00CE6282h
    0037128c 00 40 a0 e1              cpy             r4, param_1
    00371290 01 50 a0 e1              cpy             r5, param_2
    00371294 06 60 8f e0              add             r6, pc, r6
    00371298 00 00 d6 e5              ldrb            param_1, [r6,#0x0]=>DAT_0105751e                                                                        ; = ??
    0037129c 00 00 50 e3              cmp             param_1, #0x0
    003712a0 05 00 00 1a              bne             LAB_003712bc
    003712a4 f4 00 9f e5              ldr             param_1, [DAT_003713a0]                                                                                 ; = 00CC11A8h
    003712a8 00 00 9f e7              ldr             param_1, [pc,param_1]=>PTR_DAT_01032458                                                                 ; = 00d954fc
    003712ac 00 00 90 e5              ldr             param_1=>__DT_SYMTAB[671].st_size, [param_1,#0x0]=>DAT_00d954fc                                          ; = 00002BE8h
    003712b0 2b be fd eb              bl              thunk_FUN_0029b5bc                                                                                     ; undefined thunk_FUN_0029b5bc()
    003712b4 01 00 a0 e3              mov             param_1, #0x1
    003712b8 00 00 c6 e5              strb            param_1, [r6,#0x0]=>DAT_0105751e                                                                        ; = ??
                    LAB_003712bc                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 003712a0(j)  
    003712bc e0 60 9f e5              ldr             r6, [DAT_003713a4]                                                                                      ; = 00CC1060h
    003712c0 06 60 9f e7              ldr             r6, [pc,r6]=>->Class$PlayingSceneController                                                             ; = 010df7d8
    003712c4 00 00 96 e5              ldr             param_1, [r6,#0x0]=>Class$PlayingSceneController                                                        ; = ??
    003712c8 5c 00 90 e5              ldr             param_1, [param_1,#0x5c]
    003712cc 00 00 d0 e5              ldrb            param_1, [param_1,#0x0]
    003712d0 00 00 50 e3              cmp             param_1, #0x0
    003712d4 25 00 00 0a              beq             LAB_00371370
    003712d8 c8 00 9f e5              ldr             param_1, [DAT_003713a8]                                                                                 ; = 00CC02B0h
    003712dc 10 5a 09 ee              vmov            s18, r5
    003712e0 00 00 9f e7              ldr             param_1, [pc,param_1]=>->Method$CapsuleGame.CapsuleSingleton<CapsuleExecute>.get_Instance()             ; = 010d9080
    003712e4 00 00 90 e5              ldr             param_1, [param_1,#0x0]=>Method$CapsuleGame.CapsuleSingleton<CapsuleExecute>.get_Instance()             ; = ??
    003712e8 cb c8 19 eb              bl              CapsuleGame.CapsuleSingleton<T>$$get_Instance                                                          ; undefined CapsuleGame.CapsuleSingleton<T>$$get_Instance()
    003712ec 00 50 a0 e1              cpy             r5, param_1
    003712f0 00 00 50 e3              cmp             param_1, #0x0
    003712f4 00 00 00 1a              bne             LAB_003712fc
    003712f8 50 be fd eb              bl              thunk_FUN_00293108                                                                                     ; undefined thunk_FUN_00293108()
                    -- Flow Override: CALL_RETURN (CALL_TERMIN
                    LAB_003712fc                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 003712f4(j)  
    003712fc 00 00 96 e5              ldr             param_1, [r6,#0x0]=>Class$PlayingSceneController                                                        ; = ??
    00371300 00 20 a0 e3              mov             r2, #0x0
    00371304 54 10 d5 e5              ldrb            param_2, [r5,#0x54]
    00371308 00 8a b0 ee              vmov.f32        s16, 0x40000000
    0037130c 5c 00 90 e5              ldr             param_1, [param_1,#0x5c]
    00371310 00 00 51 e3              cmp             param_2, #0x0
    00371314 49 8a b0 0e              vmoveq.f32      s16, s18
    00371318 00 20 c0 e5              strb            r2, [param_1,#0x0]
    0037131c 88 00 9f e5              ldr             param_1, [DAT_003713ac]                                                                                 ; = 00CBFF84h
    00371320 00 00 9f e7              ldr             param_1, [pc,param_1]=>->Class$GamePref                                                                 ; = 010dc8d0
    00371324 0c 50 94 e5              ldr             r5, [r4,#0xc]
    00371328 00 00 90 e5              ldr             param_1, [param_1,#0x0]=>Class$GamePref                                                                 ; = ??
    0037132c bb 10 d0 e5              ldrb            param_2, [param_1,#0xbb]
    00371330 02 00 11 e3              tst             param_2, #0x2
    00371334 03 00 00 0a              beq             LAB_00371348
    00371338 74 10 90 e5              ldr             param_2, [param_1,#0x74]
    0037133c 00 00 51 e3              cmp             param_2, #0x0
    00371340 00 00 00 1a              bne             LAB_00371348
    00371344 34 be fd eb              bl              thunk_FUN_002948b8                                                                                     ; undefined thunk_FUN_002948b8()
                    LAB_00371348                                                                                                        XREF[2]: 00371334(j), 00371340(j)  
    00371348 05 00 a0 e1              cpy             param_1, r5
    0037134c 00 10 a0 e3              mov             param_2, #0x0
    00371350 5b 7d 03 eb              bl              GamePref$$updateScore                                                                                  ; void GamePref$$updateScore(int param_1)
    00371354 40 8a b5 ee              vcmp.f32        s16, #0
    00371358 10 fa f1 ee              vmrs            apsr, fpscr
    0037135c 05 00 00 1a              bne             LAB_00371378
    00371360 04 00 a0 e1              cpy             param_1, r4
    00371364 04 8b bd ec              vpop            {d8,d9}
    00371368 70 4c bd e8              ldmia           sp!,{r4 r5 r6 r10 r11 lr}
    0037136c 75 00 00 ea              b               PlayingSceneController$$showGameOverMenu                                                               ; undefined PlayingSceneController$$showGameOverMenu()
                    -- Flow Override: CALL_RETURN (CALL_TERMIN
                    LAB_00371370                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 003712d4(j)  
    00371370 04 8b bd ec              vpop            {d8,d9}
    00371374 70 8c bd e8              ldmia           sp!,{r4 r5 r6 r10 r11 pc}
                    LAB_00371378                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 0037135c(j)  
    00371378 10 1a 18 ee              vmov            param_2, s16
    0037137c 04 00 a0 e1              cpy             param_1, r4
    00371380 47 01 00 eb              bl              PlayingSceneController$$showGameOverMenu                                                               ; undefined PlayingSceneController$$showGameOverMenu()
    00371384 00 10 a0 e1              cpy             param_2, param_1
    00371388 04 00 a0 e1              cpy             param_1, r4
    0037138c 00 20 a0 e3              mov             r2, #0x0
    00371390 04 8b bd ec              vpop            {d8,d9}
    00371394 70 4c bd e8              ldmia           sp!,{r4 r5 r6 r10 r11 lr}
    00371398 41 48 11 ea              b               UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour$$StartCoroutine                                                              ; undefined UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour$$StartCoroutine()
                    -- Flow Override: CALL_RETURN (CALL_TERMIN
                    DAT_0037139c                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 00371288(R)  
    0037139c 82 62 ce 00              undefined4      00CE6282h
                    DAT_003713a0                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 003712a4(R)  
    003713a0 a8 11 cc 00              undefined4      00CC11A8h
                    DAT_003713a4                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 003712bc(R)  
    003713a4 60 10 cc 00              undefined4      00CC1060h
                    DAT_003713a8                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 003712d8(R)  
    003713a8 b0 02 cc 00              undefined4      00CC02B0h
                    DAT_003713ac                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 0037131c(R)  
    003713ac 84 ff cb 00              undefined4      00CBFF84h
```

the specific part I was concentrating is this part:

```
                    LAB_00371348                                                                                                        XREF[2]: 00371334(j), 00371340(j)  
    00371348 05 00 a0 e1              cpy             param_1, r5
    0037134c 00 10 a0 e3              mov             param_2, #0x0
    00371350 5b 7d 03 eb              bl              updateScore                                                                                  
    00371354 40 8a b5 ee              vcmp.f32        s16, #0
    00371358 10 fa f1 ee              vmrs            apsr, fpscr
    0037135c 05 00 00 1a              bne             LAB_00371378
    00371360 04 00 a0 e1              cpy             param_1, r4
    00371364 04 8b bd ec              vpop            {d8,d9}
    00371368 70 4c bd e8              ldmia           sp!,{r4 r5 r6 r10 r11 lr}
    0037136c 75 00 00 ea              b               showGameOverMenu                                                               ; undefined showGameOverMenu()
                    -- Flow Override: CALL_RETURN (CALL_TERMIN
```

I wanted to change the value of `param_1` got called with the function  `updateScore` and assign `param_1` with the `249F0` using ghidra like for example `MOV  param_1, #0x249F0` using `patch instruction` command but that was not possible. BTW now `param_1` was copied the value of `r5` which was assigned value by previous instructions but I am unable to modify it.

all in all, How can I assign `0x249F0` value on `param_1` or even `r5' registers? is this possible? is there another way I could have achieved this goal?

Edit: HERE IS DECOMPILED `updateScore` function:

```
                    ********************************************
                    *                 FUNCTION                 *
                    ********************************************
                    void __stdcall updateScore(int param_1)
         void               <VOID>           <RETURN>
         int                r0:4             param_1
                    GamePref$$updateScore                                                                                               XREF[1]: PlayingSceneController$$gameOver:00371350(c)  
    004508c4 30 48 2d e9              stmdb           sp!,{r4 r5 r11 lr}
    004508c8 08 b0 8d e2              add             r11, sp, #0x8
    004508cc a0 50 9f e5              ldr             r5, [DAT_00450974]                                                                                      ; = 00C07326h
    004508d0 00 40 a0 e1              cpy             r4, param_1
    004508d4 05 50 8f e0              add             r5, pc, r5
    004508d8 00 00 d5 e5              ldrb            param_1, [r5,#0x0]=>DAT_01057c02                                                                        ; = ??
    004508dc 00 00 50 e3              cmp             param_1, #0x0
    004508e0 05 00 00 1a              bne             LAB_004508fc
    004508e4 8c 00 9f e5              ldr             param_1, [DAT_00450978]                                                                                 ; = 00BE6778h
    004508e8 00 00 9f e7              ldr             param_1, [pc,param_1]=>PTR_DAT_01037068                                                                 ; = 00d91bf4
    004508ec 00 00 90 e5              ldr             param_1=>__DT_SYMTAB[443].st_name+1, [param_1,#0x0]=>DAT_00d91bf4                                        ; = 00001DA1h
    004508f0 9b 40 fa eb              bl              thunk_FUN_0029b5bc                                                                                     ; undefined thunk_FUN_0029b5bc()
    004508f4 01 00 a0 e3              mov             param_1, #0x1
    004508f8 00 00 c5 e5              strb            param_1, [r5,#0x0]=>DAT_01057c02                                                                        ; = ??
                    LAB_004508fc                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 004508e0(j)  
    004508fc 78 50 9f e5              ldr             r5, [DAT_0045097c]                                                                                      ; = 00BE09A4h
    00450900 05 50 9f e7              ldr             r5, [pc,r5]=>->Class$GamePref                                                                           ; = 010dc8d0
    00450904 00 00 95 e5              ldr             param_1, [r5,#0x0]=>Class$GamePref                                                                      ; = ??
    00450908 bb 10 d0 e5              ldrb            r1, [param_1,#0xbb]
    0045090c 02 00 11 e3              tst             r1, #0x2
    00450910 03 00 00 0a              beq             LAB_00450924
    00450914 74 10 90 e5              ldr             r1, [param_1,#0x74]
    00450918 00 00 51 e3              cmp             r1, #0x0
    0045091c 00 00 00 1a              bne             LAB_00450924
    00450920 bd 40 fa eb              bl              thunk_FUN_002948b8                                                                                     ; undefined thunk_FUN_002948b8()
                    LAB_00450924                                                                                                        XREF[2]: 00450910(j), 0045091c(j)  
    00450924 15 00 00 eb              bl              getScore                                                                                     ; undefined getScore()
    00450928 04 00 50 e1              cmp             param_1, r4
    0045092c 30 88 bd a8              ldmiage         sp!,{r4 r5 r11 pc}
    00450930 00 00 95 e5              ldr             param_1, [r5,#0x0]=>Class$GamePref                                                                      ; = ??
    00450934 bb 10 d0 e5              ldrb            r1, [param_1,#0xbb]
    00450938 02 00 11 e3              tst             r1, #0x2
    0045093c 04 00 00 0a              beq             LAB_00450954
    00450940 74 10 90 e5              ldr             r1, [param_1,#0x74]
    00450944 00 00 51 e3              cmp             r1, #0x0
    00450948 01 00 00 1a              bne             LAB_00450954
    0045094c b2 40 fa eb              bl              thunk_FUN_002948b8                                                                                     ; undefined thunk_FUN_002948b8()
    00450950 00 00 95 e5              ldr             param_1, [r5,#0x0]=>Class$GamePref                                                                      ; = ??
                    LAB_00450954                                                                                                        XREF[2]: 0045093c(j), 00450948(j)  
    00450954 5c 00 90 e5              ldr             param_1, [param_1,#0x5c]
    00450958 04 10 a0 e1              cpy             r1, r4
    0045095c 00 20 a0 e3              mov             r2, #0x0
    00450960 08 00 90 e5              ldr             param_1, [param_1,#0x8]
    00450964 aa b8 12 eb              bl              UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs$$SetInt                                                                        ; undefined UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs$$SetInt()
    00450968 00 00 a0 e3              mov             param_1, #0x0
    0045096c 30 48 bd e8              ldmia           sp!,{r4 r5 r11 lr}
    00450970 39 ba 12 ea              b               UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs$$Save                                                                          ; undefined UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs$$Save()
                    -- Flow Override: CALL_RETURN (CALL_TERMIN
                    DAT_00450974                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 004508cc(R)  
    00450974 26 73 c0 00              undefined4      00C07326h
                    DAT_00450978                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 004508e4(R)  
    00450978 78 67 be 00              undefined4      00BE6778h
                    DAT_0045097c                                                                                                        XREF[1]: 004508fc(R)  
    0045097c a4 09 be 00              undefined4      00BE09A4h
```

Comment: Which architecture is `libil2cpp.so` compiled for?

Comment: @raspiduino, armv7 in this case.

Comment: Strange, I have never seen `cpy` instruction in ARMv7, maybe this is generated by Ghidra to make it easier to RE?

Comment: Of course, previously searched on google and make such conclusions that ghidra decompiler somehow put in there for simplicity or may be. But any idea to achieve such goal?

Comment: Hmm, I think to load the value `0x249F0`, we need 2 instructions. Is the function `updateScore` called anywhere else or just this place? If it's not anywhere else, you can disassembly the function `updateScore`, then set the first argument to always equal to `0x249F0`.

Comment: @raspiduino I have edited the question and added the decompiled `updateScore` fucntion. take a look plz.

Comment: I can't think of anyway other than storing the value `0x249F0` to an unused place in the binary, then use `LDR` to load it from its address to the `param_1`. Hopefully someone will think of a better way to do it

Answer (score 2):

ARM limits the values of constants you can use in the MOV instruction: The complete MOV instruction needs to fit into 32 bits, so there is no space for an arbitrary 32-bit constant. Probably 0x25000 would be possible. If it needs to be 0x249F0 exactly, there is no chance to put that into the 32-bit space occupied by `mov param_2, #0`

Using LDR in PC-relative mode, and storing 0x249F0 in free space close to the instruction might work, but you would need to find a free 32-bit slot yourself first.

Comment: thanks for the idea, I have solved it using like `movn` which when negated the value gives the expected value. hey pal can you give me some ideas to this question:: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30805/find-constant-variables-with-float-values-using-ghidra