# Find constant variables with float values using Ghidra

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, decompile, c#, game-hacking

I dumped an `il2cpp.so` with `il2cppDumper` and in the `dump.cs` I found that the variables I wanted to change its values are somewhat constant float. this is the snippet:

```
// Namespace: 
public class GameConfig // TypeDefIndex: 6152
{
    // Fields
    public const float durationSlide = 1.2; // 0x0
    public const float durationBlockDame = 0.1; // 0x0
    public const float forceOnBreak = 2000; // 0x0
    public const float durationBombExp = 1.8; // 0x0
    public const float durationUpdateDistance = 0.1; // 0x0
    public const float durationCheckRange = 2; // 0x0

    // Methods
    // RVA: 0x3F5E98 Offset: 0x3F5E98 VA: 0x3F5E98
    public void .ctor() { }
}
```

And then loaded the `lib` into `ghidra` and then `auto analyze` command, while in my understanding those variables could be in that `.rodata` section but needed help of how can I identify those values like for example `1.8` which equals in hex `0x3fe66666` tried to search those values but not able to get it.
on the `.rodata` section contained so much data like this:

```
                                                  //
                                                  // .rodata 
                                                  // SHT_PROGBITS  [0x16d1e10 - 0x18b4417]
                                                  // ram:016d1e10-ram:018b4417
                                                  //
                                                  DAT_016d1e10                                                                                                                                                                              XREF[144]:      01a78090(*), 01a78098(*), 01a780a0(*), 01a780a8(*), 01a780b0(*), 01a780b8(*), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   01a780c0(*), 01a780c8(*), 01a780d0(*), 01a780d8(*), 01a780e0(*), 01a780e8(*), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   01a780f0(*), 01a83ef4(*), 01bacdd4(*), 01bace2c(*), 01bace30(*), 01bace40(*), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   01bace80(*), 01bace84(*), [more]
     016d1e10  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
      016d1e11 01                          ??                                                    01h
      016d1e12  00                          ??                                                    00h
      016d1e13  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e14  00                          ??                                                    00h
      016d1e15  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e16  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
      016d1e17  00                          ??                                                    00h
                                                  DAT_016d1e18                                                                                                                                                                              XREF[1]:          01a94444(*)  
     016d1e18  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
     016d1e19  01                          ??                                                    01h
      016d1e1a  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e1b  00                          ??                                                    00h
      016d1e1c 01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e1d  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e1e  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
      016d1e1f  00                          ??                                                    00h
                                                  DAT_016d1e20                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a946c0(*)  
     016d1e20  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
      016d1e21  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e22  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e23  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e24  11                           ??                                                    11h
     016d1e25  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e26  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e27  00                          ??                                                    00h
                                                  DAT_016d1e28                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a950a0(*)  
     016d1e28  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
     016d1e29  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e2a  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e2b  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e2c 36                          ??                                                    36h    6
     016d1e2d  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e2e  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e2f  00                          ??                                                    00h
                                                  DAT_016d1e30                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a9514c(*)  
     016d1e30  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
      016d1e31  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e32  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e33  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e34  02                          ??                                                    02h
     016d1e35  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e36  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e37  40                          ??                                                    40h    @
                                                  DAT_016d1e38                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a951dc(*)  
     016d1e38  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
     016d1e39  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e3a  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e3b  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e3c 03                          ??                                                    03h
     016d1e3d  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e3e  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e3f  00                          ??                                                    00h
                                                  DAT_016d1e40                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a95260(*)  
     016d1e40  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
     016d1e41  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e42  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e43  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e44  33                          ??                                                    33h    3
     016d1e45  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e46  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e47  00                          ??                                                    00h
                                                  DAT_016d1e48                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a95518(*)  
     016d1e48  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
     016d1e49  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e4a  00                          ??                                                    00h
    016d1e4b  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e4c 21                           ??                                                    21h    !
    016d1e4d  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e4e  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e4f  00                          ??                                                    00h
                                                  DAT_016d1e50                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a95998(*)  
     016d1e50  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
      016d1e51  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e52  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e53  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e54  81                          ??                                                    81h
     016d1e55  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e56  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e57  00                          ??                                                    00h
                                                  DAT_016d1e58                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a95a40(*)  
     016d1e58  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
     016d1e59  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e5a  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e5b  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e5c 00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e5d  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e5e  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e5f  40                          ??                                                    40h    @
                                                  DAT_016d1e60                                                                                                                                                                             XREF[1]:          01a95b0c(*)  
     016d1e60  6b                          ??                                                    6Bh    k
     016d1e61  01                          ??                                                    01h
     016d1e62  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e63  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e64  91                          ??                                                    91h
     016d1e65  00                          ??                                                    00h
     016d1e66  1c                           ??                                                    1Ch
     016d1e67  00                          ??                                                    00h
...
```

such data, tried using `terminatedCstring` option but still didn't do on all of it. because these are so much and don't know easy way to do this.

btw how can I search through and get the value `1.8` in the binary?

Edit : such long days and no answer I had the feeling to share the [apk game](https://apkcombo.com/mr-stick-epic-survival/stickman.ragdoll.happy.wheel/download/phone-3.3.8-apk) I was trying to reverse engineer. Hope it helps.